# On RHEL 6 or Fedora 14 is it possible to share or take over a graphical session without interrupting processes?

Tags: linux, desktop, share

What I'm trying to do is come up with a way for a user to take over another users local session on a linux box.  For example userA logs into a RHEL desktop and starts a process that lasts several hours.  UserB comes in later and wants to check progress on the status.  UserA and userB have separate accounts and can not share login information.  I've figured out how to do this for a cli session with group permissions but am looking for any method to accomplish the same thing in a graphical environment.  Additional packages are not out of the question but would prefer something from Red Hat or EPEL.

Answer (score 2):

As userB:
x11vnc -auth /home/userA/.Xauthority -display [something]

To get the [something] part, userA's ~/.config/autostart/ could have a script that simply echos $DISPLAY to a file that userB can reach.